# FireFox window.open(url,name,params) return DeadObject

Tags: firefox

const win = window.open("url","Login",{})
console.log(win)
and why win is DeadObject?
How to solve it?

Thank you very much!!!!!!!!!!

not DeadObject    idk why

Comment: Probably, your browser is configured to prevent popups from opening, so the WindowProxy you should have had access to isn't linked to its JS environment anymore and you get this (FF specific) DeadObject. Change your browser settings to allow popups (and be sure to call `open()` from a click event.